# Is there a way to ensure that an image/video received from a user was taken using the webcam?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I am building a website that needs the funcitionality of receiving only webcam video/image. Basically, I want to make sure that the user can't bypass that by being able to upload an image, which was not taken using the webcam, directly to the server. Is this possible?

I am looking for methods to implement that but couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: As PHP & Javascript/Browser are two separate entities and given that a user can spend as long as they wish crafted whatever image/video offline and adding whatever attributes they want to it there really is no means by which you can know if the source is a webcam or locally saved resource.

Comment: Realistically this isn't possible at all. Why is that the requirement? Maybe you need to rethink your process.

Comment: One much more complicated option would be to create a native app. My banking software, for instance, allows me to deposit checks by taking pictures, and it won’t allow me to upload from storage.

Comment: Or, maybe you could stream the video to an HTML canvas with a “take a picture” button that sends the blob to the server using JS? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/front-and-rear-camera-access-with-javascripts-getusermedia